# Why does my application look for both MyApp.exe.config and MyApp.config to find the app.config file

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a check to make sure the app.config file exists and to report an error if it does not:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
if (!File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile))
{

    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Unable to find configuration file.  File is expected at location:  "
    + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile + "\n");
}
```

When I build the solution, the app.config file in is added to the output directory as AppName.exe.config, and if run from outside visual studio `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` contains the path C:\path\AppName.exe.config (from within VS it's C:\path\AppName.vshost.exe.config).  If I delete AppName.exe.config, the value is C:\path\Appname.config  (no .exe).

I did a bit of farther experimentation, and if Appname.config exists that file will also work to load my setting values.

What's going on here?  I need to have everything consistent for error reporting purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reposted this on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/420f51a1-2cc7-4e9b-9a7a-dcb4d3e5d0ca?prof=required&ppud=4) when I didn't get an answer.  Microsoft has confirmed that this is a bug.  The official work around is to create my own app domain instead of using the default.